# SIGSEGV memcopy or memmove

Tags: android, c

I am developing an Android application using NDK. The application blows up with "SIGSEGV" error which I believe a segmentation fault error.

I looked at my code and I think memcopy and memmove might cause this error. I was wondering if there is a safe way to call these functions.

Also please let me know any well described NDK debugging tutorials or anything related. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide more detail on your usage of memcopy and memmove?  They certainly can lead to segfault, but it's usually a mistake in what memory is passed in to them.

Comment: Please post the C code where you make the memcpy/memmove calls.

Also, try printing (logging) the source and destination pointers before doing the memcpy or memmove call. Although there's no programmatic way to know whether the pointers are valid, one can often tell visually whether the pointers appear to be valid (especially true if they're 0, which is not particularly valid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule with those 2 is that you use memcpy when you're copying a block of bytes from one place to another, and the source and destination don't overlap.  If they do overlap, you have to use memmove.  However, using them incorrectly results in corrupted data, not segfaults.  Segfaults happen when you try to read or write to a memory location that is invalid - its analogous to Java's NullPointerException.  You want to triple check that you have destination, source and size in the correct order.  Beyond that, we'll need to see some code.

Comment: `However, using them incorrectly results in corrupted data, not segfaults.` Don't you agree that this statement is hogwash if your pointers are stray in the first place, and don't you agree that using stray pointers in memcpy/memmove is a pretty common source of errors?

Comment: Using invalid pointers is an entirely different class of errors, which I see as different than misusing a function.  However, I should have been more clear.  By 'using incorrectly', I meant one of 2 situations: using memcpy where you should have used memmove (when source and destination overlap), or flipping the source and destination operands.  Both of these result in data corruption, not segfaults.  And I would imagine they are both far more common than using invalid pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's "logcat" logging facility within NDK code, so if you need to understand where things are going bad, that can be pretty helpful (unless you're able to run gdb / gdbserver).

It's very possible that memcpy or memmov can cause a SIGSEGV. You need to be sure all your pointers are correct, and the buffer sizes are correct as well. If you make a mistake there, the best that can happen is your SIGSEGV and program crash. On the worse end, you could overwrite other memory in your application and not know until some time later (making it difficult to find the cause of the corruption).

Comment: the logcat only gives me the stack trace with memory addresses. I was trying to convert that into English with the python script from Google code but it didn't work. It didn't complain anything but didn't generate an output file either...Please let me know if there is another way to use logcat to debug this kind of issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My reference to logcat wasn't so much about the crash entries (though it's possible to convert that to something useful, I don't have the details). What I meant was using logcat as a printf() to help you log your own messages to narrow down the point of failure. http://konkanok.com/2011/02/printing-to-logcat-from-c/ gives you the details needed to print to the log from your native code.